# sending messages to Azure Event Hubs in .NET Standard to a specfic consumer group

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

i have requirement data coming from different country

like
country-a- Consumer Group-a
country-b  -Consumer Group-b

i use this example given in site
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send

in given code where i put my consumergroup name

Comment: You don't send to a particular Consumer Group.  You send messages to an Event Hub and each Consumer Group sees all the Messages.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups

Comment: thanks for replay, but how i know which consumer group receive data from each country thread, when i read data in stream analytic input i want read country a data in country A folder, it should not mixed with   countery B data

Answer (score 1):

You can't send events to just one consumer group: that goes against the principle of Event Hubs (and similar pub-sub services).

Instead, you need to choose between sending to separate event hubs (split on producer side) or filter events on consumer side. You could partition your events on country, if that makes sense for your use case.